# Extensions of scalars and tangent map of morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose I have a morphism of rings $\varphi: A \to B$, $M$ a $B$-module, $N$ an $A$-module and $f: M \to N$ a homomorphism of $A$-modules (here, $M$ is considered an $A$-module by restriction of scalars). How do I properly "extend" $f$ to a morphism of $B$-modules $F: M \to N \otimes_A B$? You may assume that $A, B$ are fields, and $M, N$ are vector spaces.

I'm asking this because I'm confused about the definition of the map $df_x: T_xX \to T_{f(x)} Y \otimes_{k(f(x))} k(x)$ for a morphism of schemes $f: X \to Y$. I know that we have a $k(f(x))$-linear map $T: \frac{\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}}{\mathfrak{m}^2_{f(x)}} \to \frac{\mathfrak{m}_x}{\mathfrak{m}^2_x}$ induced from the map of stalks $f^\#_x: \mathcal{O}_{Y, f(x)} \to \mathcal{O}_{X, x}$ - $k(f(x)$ linearity of $T$ follows from the inclusion $k(f(x)) \to k(x)$. Taking the dual of $T$, we have a  $k(f(x))$-linear map $T^\lor: T_x X \to T_{f(x)} Y$. How is $df_x: T_xX \to T_{f(x)} Y \otimes_{k(f(x))} k(x)$ defined in terms of $T$ and $T^\lor$? I tried considering the map $T^\lor \otimes_{k(f(x))}Id_{k(x)}$ - but I wasn't sure that $T_xX \otimes_{k(f(x))} k(x) \cong T_xX$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dualization here is crucial to the existence of the map in question.  The $k(f((x))$-linear map $T:\frac{\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}}{\mathfrak{m}^2_{f(x)}} \to \frac{\mathfrak{m}_x}{\mathfrak{m}^2_x}$ induces a $k(x)$-linear map $T':\frac{\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}}{\mathfrak{m}^2_{f(x)}}\otimes_{k(f(x))}k(x) \to \frac{\mathfrak{m}_x}{\mathfrak{m}^2_x}$ by $T'(v\otimes a)=aT(v)$.  The map $df_x$ is then defined as the dual of this map $T'$ over $k(x)$, identifying the $k(x)$-dual of $\frac{\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}}{\mathfrak{m}^2_{f(x)}}\otimes_{k(f(x))}k(x)$ with $\left(\frac{\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}}{\mathfrak{m}^2_{f(x)}}\right)^\vee\otimes_{k(f(x))}k(x)$ (which only works if either $\frac{\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}}{\mathfrak{m}^2_{f(x)}}$ or $k(x)$ is finite-dimensional over $k(f(x))$).

Comment: Wait, if we have a map $\frac{\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}}{\mathfrak{m}^2_{f(x)}} \otimes_{k(f(x))} k(x) \to \frac{\mathfrak{m}_x}{\mathfrak{m}^2_x}$, its dual would be a map $T_xX \to T_{f(x)} Y \otimes_{k(f(x))} k(x)^\lor$ - and assuming that $k(x)$ is isomorphic to $k(x)^\lor$ as a $k(f(x))$ vector space, then $df_x$ would depend on the isomorphism, right?

Comment: We're taking the dual over $k(x)$, not over $k(f(x))$.

Comment: Taking the dual over $k(x)$ still makes the dual operation distribute over tensor products?

Comment: Sorry, it isn't obvious to me

Comment: No, that wouldn't even make sense (there is no such thing as the dual of $\frac{\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}}{\mathfrak{m}^2_{f(x)}}$ over $k(x)$).  What is true is: if $k\subseteq K$ is a field extension and $V$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space, then the $K$-dual of $V\otimes_k K$ is naturally isomorphic to $V^\vee\otimes_k K$.

Comment: To prove this, note that there is a canonical $k$-linear map $V^\vee\to (V\otimes_k K)^\vee$, since any functional $V\to k$ induces a functional $V\otimes_k K\to K$ by tensoring with $K$.  This then induces a $K$-linear map $V^\vee\otimes_k K\to (V\otimes_k K)^\vee$.

Comment: To prove that this canonical map is an isomorphism, you can just pick a basis for $V$ and see what the map does in terms of the basis.  (You need $V$ to be finite-dimensional so that a chosen basis for $V$ gives a basis on the dual.)

Comment: Yeah, I asked it poorly, there are two different dualizing operations. I will figure out the details, thank you